# Xaml how to use operands in attribute

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

do you know how to use math operands in xaml for example i have this:

```
 <TextBlock Foreground="Red" Text="Example 01" FontSize="{Binding ElementName=SizeTextBox,  Path=Text.Length}"   Background="Azure"/>
```

and want to have something like this:

```
  FontSize="{Binding ElementName=SizeTextBox,  Path=Text.Length*4}"
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: You can't use math operand, you have to use a ValueConverter.

Comment: You can't do that in XAML, you have to use `IValueConverter` to achieve that.

Comment: [This might help](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29621/The-Last-IValueConverter)